# Clients try to connect to redis with old password

Tags: laravel, redis, horizon

I have a Debian 10 server with Laravel 5.8.
This is the redis configuration in `config/database.php`:

```
'redis' => [

    'client' => 'predis',

    'default' => [
      'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
      'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
      'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
      'database' => 0,
      'read_write_timeout' => 60,
    ],

    'cache' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 1),
    ],

  ],
```

In `.env` file I have only the `REDIS_PASSWORD` param, that is the same in redis-server configuration.
I noticed that some emails remain in the queue for a long time, for no apparent reason.
Checking the Redis log with `redis-server monitor` I see that several clients try to connect even with old test passwords that were present in the `.env` file.
`php artisan config:cache` and similar were not helpful.

Test passwords are no longer present in the .env file and in no other file; how and where can they be saved? How do I get rid of them permanently?

Thanks

Comment: Check for the ip addresses while you are trying to `monitor` it. It may give you a clue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart the queue, as it caches your code entirely including config.

Quote from [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues):

> Remember, queue workers are long-lived processes and store the booted
> application state in memory. As a result, they will not notice changes
> in your code base after they have been started. So, during your
> deployment process, be sure to restart your queue workers. In
> addition, remember that any static state created or modified by your
> application will not be automatically reset between jobs.

Comment: It doesn't works. In redis-cli monitor I have always an AUTH with old password.